How should we rationalize our tag scheme?
Many common topics on the site have multiple overlapping tags covering the same or similar areas.  The specific tags I have in mind are:
Risk

risk
risk-management
risk-models
coherent-risk-measure
risk-neutral
risk-neutrality
risk-premium

Research/reference request

research
reference
reference-request

Models

model
models
modeling
data-model

Options

option
options
option-pricing
option-price
option-strategies
black-scholes
black-scholes-formula
implied-volatility
greeks
delta-neutral
gamma

Equity

stock
stocks
stock-prices
stock-selection
equity

Fixed Income

fixed-income
bonds
interest-rates

Data

data
market-data
database
databases
data-model
tick-data
historical-data
real-time-data

Please edit the question to add any others I've left out.
At the moment, the system only seems to allow moderators to propose tag synonyms, since few if any of us have enough reputation in each tag to propose tag synonyms ourselves.
I'm not sure how to organize the discussion.  Perhaps we can set up a chat time to discuss this.  Perhaps each answer should propose a set of synonyms in a given topic, and others can up-vote to show their approval for that set of synonyms.  Some other SE sites often have a few rather verbose tag names, with almost all popular variants automatically redirecting to those.  I think we should adopt the same practice here.

Looks like we should add a tag for "random matrix theory"

@Louis Marascio says:
I'd rather see a set of tags that represent that commonly accepted industry term. For example: equities, fixed-income, fx, futures, options, swaps, etc. Then redirect those synonyms that might be required: stocks -> equities, etc. Not sure overly verbose tag names like stocks-equity would be any more useful or informative to the community than just equities. The breakdown of options, derivatives, etc would need some thought, but I don't think there is any harm in having a question tagged options and derivatives at the same time. After all, its a taxonomy, not a hierarchy.

For the major asset classes, I propose that all popular variants redirect to tags of the form layman's-term-technical-term namely stocks-equity and bonds-fixed-income.  In accordance with this, we may also want to rename the fx tag currencies-foreign-exchange.
All vanilla options terms should be consolidated under options, or perhaps vanilla-options, while derivatives should be reserved for derivatives which are neither options nor futures (which also has its own tag).  Alternatively, we can disallow the derivatives tag altogether, with OTC derivatives such as vanilla swaps, caps and floors, CDS, quantos, variance/volatility swaps, ... getting their own tags.

I'd rather see a set of tags that represent that commonly accepted industry term. For example: equities, fixed-income, fx, futures, options, swaps, etc. Then redirect those synonyms that might be required: stocks -> equities, etc. Not sure overly verbose tag names like stocks-equity would be any more useful or informative to the community than just equities. The breakdown of options, derivatives, etc would need some thought, but I don't think there is any harm in having a question tagged options and derivatives at the same time. After all, its a taxonomy, not a hierarchy.

I'm with Louis here. stocks-equity and bonds-fixed-income seem too convoluted. Consensus here is we're aiming at a professional user, so IMO layman's terms should be avoided. As a convenience for readers, we could use layman's tag synonyms instead. And another thing from a quick perusal - I would drop finance tag completely, it seems redundant for a Quantitative Finance site.

I've posted your comment as an answer so you and others can vote on it.  For those of us with tag synonimizer privileges, let's start implementing Louis's suggestion (I was on the fence myself between that and what I wrote, just wanted to put it out there for others' opinions).
